# Jquery, ASP.NET MVP and data synch... dilemma

Tags: data-binding, jquery, mvp

Ok. this is my situation.

I am working on a website. It's on ASP.NET and i am using MVP pattern. I am very curious about Jquery (and Jquery Ajax) and i need to do a lot of ajax/asynchronous calls throughtout my website.

But, i faced my first challenge... and i am clueless. I have a webform with two usercontrols. One is a datagrid with all the Clock In/Out of the employee for the week. The other user controls is nothing but a label showing the current status of the employee (Clocked In or Out) and a button to perform the corresponding action (clock the employee in or out)

so, technically, when the page loads, it loads the grid with 10 records in one UC (usercontrol)... then when we click on the button in the other UC, i want to add that new record to the grid using jquery ajax.

i don't see how. And the way i see it possible... i better do a full refresh because it's like using a cannon to kill a fly.

let's say i click on the button... $mybutton.click(){ ajax call to add new record } ... that's no problem. Now, how the datagrid "knows" about this new record? do i have to create a new ajax call for the grid to load the new data once i get a onsuccess from my previous ajax call?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would scratch the DataGrid altogether, and make my web page get the entire data grid via AJAX.

You'll have to populate the grid yourself and add it to the page DOM. It's easy to do with jQuery.

Then you make your AJAX call to add a new record, and add this record to the grid using the same function you used when you were populating the grid initially.

Comment: The way i see it... jquery eventually will eliminate "code behind"... all the "logic" in code behind will be passed to a webservice and basically we will be going back to the classic asp with web services. that's how i see it honestly. codebehind is getting obsolete.

Comment: By the way, @Zruty, your solution seems to be the right one but still, sounds like A LOT OF WORK for such a simple thing like populating a datagrid. it sounds to me you're a php or mvc developer?

Comment: No, I'm an ASP.NET developer. But the ASP.NET concept of UpdatePanels seems very ugly to me, so I switched to using AJAX for populating the updatable grids. Then I moved to ASP.NET MVC framework, and now I can evade writing HTML inside my JavaScript (and write it inside my MVC partial views instead, which I then load with AJAX)

Comment: P.S. And yes, it seems a bit overweight for such a simple task. However, you get better flexibility this way, and you separate your processing from your visual representation

Comment: I agree with you about the UpdatePanel... the whole Msoft Ajax toolkit seems to me "too much" even thou is a breeze to work with... but performance wise... not good.

Comment: Could you show me a little sample on how you would populate the grid and do all that i'm trying to? i would appreciate it. i am trying to grasp the concept.